# First Option is not showing in select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using select field with some options but the first options is not showing in the front-end,but when i do inspect element it is there in the select filed but it is not showing.

```
<select id="fruits" class="select2-offscreen"    name="fruits" tabindex="-1">
 <option value="apple">Apple</option>
 <option value="orange">Orange</option>
 <option value="banana">banana</option>
 <option value="mango">mango</option>
 <option value="grapes">grapes</option>
</select>
```

The value apple is not showing in the dropdown but it is there when i do inspect.i want to display all the values in dropdown

Comment: can't repro the issue

Comment: Must be something in your code, without providing more information we cant help you

Comment: Every thing is working fine here : https://jsfiddle.net/gpt464et/ The issue is with in your code

Comment: yes, thankyou all. it is was the class overriding issues, will check once.